# AWS Elastic Beanstalk : How to change node command ? Container Options removed in recent update?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, procfile

I had deployed a node.js application on Elastic Beanstalk recently and it gave me container options so that I could change the command to be run on startup.

[image]

But in the recent update I suppose they've removed this option, now how do I configure my on-startup command?

[image]

Comment: For single instance container, just specify it in `Dockerfile`. For ecs docker, you have `Dockerrun.aws.json` file.

Comment: Very sorry , I'm new to elastic beanstalk please provide detailed steps!

Comment: Its too generic to describe it. What I can recommend is, to try doing it yourself based on aws docs, and then make new question with more specific issues.

Comment: Okay....sure ! I will do that and get back

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AWS has changed the process recently. Now you have to upload a `Procfile` with all your application files. The same approach exists in `Heroku` as well.

The content of `Procfile` should be:

`web: node index.js` (i.e specify the node command to be run for your application)

Official Documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html

Comment: not that simple doesn't work

Comment: Worked perfectly in my case. Just needed to also make sure the Procfile made it's way into my zip and updated the command to point to the build folder but it all depends on how you have your app set up.